# Subsetting a data set and plotting means

Tags: r

I have a data set including Year, Site, and Species Count. I am trying to write a code that reflects in some years, the counts were done twice. For those years I have to find the mean count at each site for each species (there are two different species), and plot those means. This is the code I have generated:

```
DataSet1 <- subset(channel_islands, 
                   channel_islands$SpeciesName=="Hypsypops ubicundus, adult" |
                   channel_islands$SpeciesName=="Paralabrax clathratus,adult")
years<-unique(DataSet1$Year)

Hypsypops_mean <- NULL
Paralabrax_mean <- NULL
Mean <- NULL
years <- unique(DataSet1$Year)

for(i in 1:length(years)){

  data_year <- DataSet1[which(DataSet1$Year == years[i]), ]
  Hypsypops<-data_year[which(data_year$SpeciesName=="Hypsypops rubicundus,adult"), ]
  Paralabrax<-data_year[which(data_year$SpeciesName=="Paralabrax clathratus,adult"), ]

  UNIQUESITE<-unique(unique(data_year$Site))

  for(m in 1:(length(UNIQUESITE))){
    zz<-Hypsypops[Hypsypops$Site==m,]

    if(length(zz$Site)>=2){
      Meanp <- mean(Hypsypops$Count[Hypsypops$Site==UNIQUESITE[m]])
      Hypsypops_mean <- rbind(Hypsypops_mean, 
                             c(UNIQUESITE[m], years[i], round(Meanp,2), 
                               'Hypsypops rubicundus,adult'))
    }

    kk <- Paralabrax[Paralabrax$Site==m, ]

    if(length(kk$Site)>=2){
       Meane <- mean(Paralabrax$Count[Paralabrax$Site==UNIQUESITE[m]])
       Paralabrax_mean <- rbind(Paralabrax_mean, 
                                c(UNIQUESITE[m], years[i], round(Meane, 2),
                                  'Paralabrax clathratus,adult'))
    }
  }

  if(i==1){
    Mean<-rbind(Hypsypops_mean, Paralabrax_mean)
  }

  if(i>1){
    Mean<-rbind(DataMean, Hypsypops_mean, Paralabrax_mean)
  }

  Hypsypops_mean<-NULL
  Paralabrax_mean<-NULL
}

Mean <- as.data.frame(Mean,stringsAsFactors=F)
names(Mean) <- c('Site','Year','mean_count','SpeciesName')

Mean$Site <- as.integer(Mean$Site)
Mean$Year <- as.integer(Mean$Year)
Mean$mean_count <- as.numeric(Mean$mean_count)

par(mfrow=c(5,5), oma=c(4,2,4,2), mar=c(5.5,4,3,0))
for(i in 1:length(years)){

  if(any(Mean$Year==years[i])) {
    year1<-Mean[which(Mean$Year==years[i]),]

    Species<-unique(as.character(year1$SpeciesName))
    Colors<-c("pink","purple")[Species]

    Data_Hr<-year1[year1$SpeciesName=="Hypsypops rubicundus,adult",]
    Data_Pc<-year1[year1$SpeciesName=="Paralabrax clathratus,adult",]

    plot(Data_Hr$mean_count~Data_Pc$mean_count,
       xlab=c("Hypsypops rubicundus"),
       ylab=c("Paralabrax clathratus"),main=years[i],pch=16)
  }
}
```

It's a lot I'm sorry, I'm not sure of a way to streamline the process. But I keep getting an error:

> Error in names(Mean) <- c("Site", "Year", "mean_count", "SpeciesName")
>   :    'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Not sure how I can debug this.

Comment: within the code add a line just above the line that's erroring like `print(Mean)` and see what it looks like. I suspects it's NULL or something

Comment: @RAB it runs but doesn't give me any kind of output

Comment: my deebugging trick is to put `cat('here1\n')`, `cat('here2\n')` etc at various points throughout the loop to see where it gets to before stopping. Then, just before it gets to the bit where it stops use cat or print to output all of the parameters about to be used in the line that is causing issues.

Comment: @RAB yes the print function outputs 0 rows or 0-length row.names. I can't figure out why it's outputting essentially nothing when I run the code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this with an elaborate loop code. It sounds like you are trying to summarise your data.

This can be done in different ways. Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
DataSet1 %>%
  group_by(Year, SpeciesName, Site) %>%
  summarise(nrecords = n(),
            Count = mean(Count))
```

To get a better answer, it might be helpful to post a subset of the data and the intended result you are after.